# Update from multiple tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, null, sql-update

I'm trying to construct a query in which I update `table_a` with data contained in both `table_b` and `table_c`.

All the `UPDATE ... FROM` docs and questions I've found seem to be focused on updating `table_a` with data in `table_c` by joining through `table_b`. I don't want that, I need to use data contained in both `table_b` and `table_c`, which are both left joined to `table_a`

An example select would be:

```
SELECT 
        a.id 
    ,   b.counted as count_b
    ,   c.counted as count_c
FROM 
    table_a a
LEFT JOIN
    table_b b on a.id = b.id
LEFT JOIN
    table_c c on a.id = c.id
;


 id | count_b | count_c
----+---------+---------
 34 |       6 |       2
 43 |      16 |       2
 45 |      33 |       5
```

Working 'one table'-updates are:

```
UPDATE table_a SET count_b = table_b.counted
FROM table_b WHERE table_a.id = table_b.id;

UPDATE table_a SET count_c = table_c.counted
FROM table_c WHERE table_a.id = table_c.id;
```

However I'd like to combine them for efficiency (update is an insert+delete, so there's a bit of savings to be had. But I can't seem to figure out how to join two tables onto `table_a` in an `UPDATE ... FROM`.

I could handle this with a subquery - but I'd prefer avoiding that.

Comment: Important questions that make a difference: Are `a.id`, `b.id`, `c.id` *unique*? Can each of them be *missing*? Can `counted` or `count_b` etc. be *NULL*?

Comment: b.id and c.id are both a subset of a.id ; it is possible that there will not be a b.id or c.id (which is why i used a left join).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>To shorten my longish answer I work with table names `a`, `b`, `c`.</sup>
If `a.id`, `b.id` and `c.id` are **`UNIQUE`** (but can be missing):

**Basic form** with a number of caveats (keep reading!):

```
UPDATE a
SET    count_b = b.counted
     , count_c = c.counted
FROM   b
FULL   JOIN c USING (id)
WHERE  a.id = COALESCE(b.id, c.id)
;
```

Wouldn't work properly if any of the `id` columns are not `UNIQUE` - but neither would separate updates.

If nothing actually changes (all `counted` columns identical to what's in `a` already) you would just create a dead row for full cost. If that can be the case and you want to avoid it, append an additional `WHERE` clause:

```
AND   (a.count_b <> b.counted OR
       a.count_c <> c.counted)  -- simple form with all columns NOT NULL
```

[**`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-FROM) makes it work if *some, but not all* tables (*one* in the simple case of *two* source tables) does not have a row for the same `id`. It effectively emulates multiple `LEFT JOIN` you had in mind, with a small but *important difference*: You get phantom `NULL` values for columns from tables where the row is missing. Catch that with `COALESCE`:

```
SET    count_b = COALESCE(b.counted, a.count_b)
```

There is *still* a corner case if `counted` can be `NULL`. `COALESCE` cannot distinguish between two cases:
1. `b.counted IS NULL`.
2. `b.counted` does not exist.
If you need the distinction, use a `CASE` statement instead:

```
SET    count_b = CASE WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN a.count_b ELSE b.counted END
```

Adapt `WHERE` clauses accordingly.
The **complete version**, covering all `NULL` cases and avoiding empty updates:

```
UPDATE a
SET    count_b = CASE WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN a.count_b ELSE b.counted END
     , count_c = CASE WHEN c.id IS NULL THEN a.count_b ELSE c.counted END
FROM   b
FULL   JOIN c USING (id)
WHERE  a.id = COALESCE(b.id, c.id)
AND   (b.id IS NOT NULL AND b.counted IS DISTINCT FROM a.count_b OR
       c.id IS NOT NULL AND c.counted IS DISTINCT FROM a.count_c)
;
```

Looks complex, but should be faster if there is substantial overlap between the source tables.

#### Correlated subqueries

If there is no matching `id` in any of the source tables, the according row in `a` is *not* updated, which is typically what you want. You could use correlated subqueries instead to update all rows, no matter what - which is typically what you don't want, but your case may differ. Correlated subqueries are also typically much more expensive for big tables.

```
UPDATE a
SET    count_b = (SELECT b.counted FROM b WHERE b.id = a.id)
     , count_c = (SELECT c.counted FROM c WHERE c.id = a.id)
```

Again, you can avoid the `NULL` values with:

```
SET    count_b = COALESCE ((SELECT b.counted ...), count_b)
```

Would still waste empty updates which you are trying to minimize. You could add a `WHERE` clause with `EXISTS` for that ...

Comment: Wow. Thank you.  You answered everything, and thought of everything. I took the coalesce out of the sample to avoid confusion, but did not think about the `CASE` for `NULL`.  In my situation, it would be 0.  There is indeed substantial overlap - I'm actually updating 6 fields from 6 different temp tables used for processing analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Not the exact query but more like a example. you can try like below, by getting the `counted` column from both `table_b` and `table_b` in a inner query and joining with it to `table_a` in update.

```
UPDATE table_a 
SET count_b = tableb_counted,
count_c = tablec_counted
FROM (
  SELECT table_b.counted as tableb_counted,
  table_b.id,
  table_c.counted as tablec_counted
  FROM table_b
  JOIN table_c
  ON table_b.id = table_c.id
) tab
WHERE table_a.id = tab.id
```

Comment: The `INNER JOIN` would exclude rows where one of (b, c) is missing.